# Joining multiple tables in the same query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables that i need to join to return results for an sms gateway. The columns that i need to be output are tblmembers.name and tblmembers.number.

I need to be able to change the following conditions according to my application but the structure should stay the same on the query, the columns that i need to be able to filter by are: tblmembers.sms, tblmembers.country_zone_id, tblmembers.country_id, tblmembers.birthdate (between x any y), tblmembers.gender, tblmembers.campid, tblmembers.poe, the second table is tblmembertiers.status (this needs to be the newest entry), the third table is accounttrans.amount (i need to be able to calculate average earn/redeem and even select the top x members), accounttrans.mercantid(need to return members who have been to a store x or more times. the last table is accounts.balance (need to be able to return members with an average balance of x)

So basically i need a query where i can sqecify all the values for the given columns and have the valid results returned.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I Think you need to give the diagram of your table so that we could solve the answer

Comment: You should also show some snippet that you have tried.

Comment: Would be good if you show up your table schema and example queries you have tried. You can also help us understand your query better by creating example table schema on http://sqlfiddle.com and share your link which can be used for reference

Comment: try to write multiple queries and use UNION (or UNION ALL) joining the results